# Rename a table using one piece of data in another table

Tags: sql

I create a table named `[Detail]`. And I want to rename the table `[Detail]`.

The new name could be the latest string in column `Title` form another table named `[Event]`.
 The `[Event]` table have two columns, `EventID`, and `Title`. `EventID` is primary key.

```
ALTER TABLE [Detail] 
RENAME to 
SELECT Title FROM [Event] 
WHERE EventID = (SELECT MAX(EventID) FROM [Event])
```

Comment: Overall, this seems like a rather bad idea, but you could do it by generating your sql query to rename the table as a string and then use `execute`. I would consider a lot more analysis as to what you are truly attempting to do here though. Unless you are trying to clone/generate tables as a process to set up a user/client, I can't really see a need to dynamically create/rename a table.

Comment: Actually, what i need is to use the latest Title in [Event] as the name of a new table.

Comment: As you're using square bracket I assume you should also tag tsql / sqlserver?

Comment: Horrible idea. In SQL we don't rename tables (on run time). If you need it as a name for a report, pick up the  title and send that as a parameter. If you'd say why you need it, we might be able to give you another solution.

Comment: I strongly advise against doing this. You are missing something. Table name should be conventional, not logical.

Comment: Not to add too much noise to the chorus but it bears repeating. Really re-consider your approach here. Tables is a structural component of databases and part of the database design stage which should be abstracted from data itself. Data points should not define properties of tables.

Answer (score 1):

Consider execute dynamic SQL commands. As suggested by @gmiley you should check whether it's necessary as there are drawbacks like security and performance issues.

```
DECLARE @NewName varchar(255)
DECLARE @sqlCommand varchar(1000)

SELECT TOP 1 @NewName = Title 
FROM [Event] 
ORDER BY ID DESC

SET @sqlCommand = 'ALTER TABLE [Detail] RENAME to ' + @NewName
EXEC (@sqlCommand)
```

Comment: Not to mention that it just smells like poor table design all over.